# oracle 12c automated install with puppet returns error but ok when run manually

Tags: oracle, automation, puppet, oracle12c

I run manual install of Oracle 12c database on centos7 in silent mode, everything is ok and I want now to automate the steps in a puppet module.

For the curious the code is at [github](https://github.com/fhenri/ariba-sourcing-tomcat/tree/oracle12c/puppet/modules/oracledb) (make sure to switch to oracle12c branch)

I run puppet to automate the install of Oracle 12c database but I am not able to created the database and the database (software has been installed)

I get the error

```
==> db: Notice: /Stage[main]/Oracle::Server/Exec[create-db]/returns: Copying database files
==> db: Notice: /Stage[main]/Oracle::Server/Exec[create-db]/returns: 1% complete
==> db: Notice: /Stage[main]/Oracle::Server/Exec[create-db]/returns: 2% complete
==> db: Notice: /Stage[main]/Oracle::Server/Exec[create-db]/returns: 3% complete
==> db: Notice: /Stage[main]/Oracle::Server/Exec[create-db]/returns: DBCA Operation failed.
==> db: Notice: /Stage[main]/Oracle::Server/Exec[create-db]/returns: Look at the log file "/oracle/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/sourcegate/sourcega.log" for further details.
==> db: Error: /bin/sh -c '/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbca -silent -createDatabase -responseFile /oracle/tmp/dbca.rsp' returned 255 instead of one of [0,3]
==> db: Error: /Stage[main]/Oracle::Server/Exec[create-db]/returns: change from notrun to 0 3 failed: /bin/sh -c '/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbca -silent -createDatabase -responseFile /oracle/tmp/dbca.rsp' returned 255 instead of one of [0,3]
```

content of the file /oracle/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/sourcegate/sourcega.log:

```
DBCA_PROGRESS : 1%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 2%
[ 2019-12-09 16:53:49.381 UTC ] ORA-00443: background process "PMON" did not start

DBCA_PROGRESS : 3%
[ 2019-12-09 16:53:49.386 UTC ] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

[ 2019-12-09 16:53:49.389 UTC ] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

[ 2019-12-09 16:53:54.722 UTC ] DBCA_PROGRESS : DBCA Operation failed.
```

I am able to complete it either:
- reboot the server and rerun the task
- when login to the server and re-run the dbca command I will get the following

```
DBCA_PROGRESS : 1%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 2%
[ 2019-12-09 16:56:55.214 UTC ] ORA-01012: not logged on

DBCA_PROGRESS : 3%
[ 2019-12-09 16:56:55.215 UTC ] ORA-01012: not logged on

[ 2019-12-09 16:56:55.228 UTC ] ORA-01012: not logged on

[ 2019-12-09 16:56:55.413 UTC ] Error while cataloging RMAN Backups
[ 2019-12-09 16:57:01.822 UTC ] DBCA_PROGRESS : DBCA Operation failed.
```

Note the change in the error. And if I rerun again (without any other change) it will work.

My env variables are correct as its working in manual mode and also when rerunning the command without any other change.

I dont think there's any delay from oracle boot as I login into the server few minutes after the fail and still the 1st attempt will always return the same error.

Comment: Things to look at: check your alert log for more details. This error is often caused by Oracle trying to allocate more memory than allowed, but it looks like you're specifying a percentage (40%) rather than an amount, so maybe it's something else.

Comment: I would agree with @kfinity. When I automated Oracle installs with developed Puppet modules, the culprit for a mysterious failing `dbca` was always over-allocation of memory for the database. Otherwise, I would suggest using `user`, `environment`, etc. attributes for the Puppet resource as Oracle also often requires those in Puppet automation for success.

Comment: Thanks  @kfinity and MattSchuchard I tweaked the response file and some swap/memory parameters, at the end it worked and install seems now to be running till the end.